# How do I specify a nested self-referential adjacency list relationship in SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have been tasked to build some web apps for internal use at my company that hide a very ugly schema used by a very old program that is still in use. I am using Python+SQLAlchemy 1.3 and the declarative ORM module. I have to maintain backwards compatibility.

Essentially, `Order`s have multiple `Line`s, and lines have multiple items (referred to by column `DELNUM_10`). `ORDNUM_10`, `LINNUM_10`, and `PRTNUM_10` together form a composite primary key that uniquely identifies a `Part` and associated info in an `Order`.

In the pictured example, I'd like a Python object like so:

```
order = {number: '2000072', lines: {1: [Part{MAT03}, Part{BSKQ03}]...}}
```

`PRTNUM_10` is a foreign key to another ORM mapped class `Part`.

[image: Orders table]

```
class Part(Base):
  __table__ = Part_Master
  SKU = __table__.columns.PRTNUM_01
  name = __table__.columns.PMDES1_01
  description = __table__.columns.PMDES2_01
  category = __table__.columns.COMCDE_01

Order_Master = Table(
  'Order_Master',
  meta,
  Column('ORDNUM_10', CHAR(length=8), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
  Column('LINNUM_10', CHAR(length=2), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
  Column('DELNUM_10', CHAR(length=2), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
  # more unholy columns
)
class Order(Base):
  __table__ = Order_Master
  number = __table__.columns.ORDNUM_10
  line = __table__.columns.LINNUM_10
  subline = __table__.columns.DELNUM_10
  lines = relationship(Order, someOtherThingToMakeItWork)
```

How can i use `relationship()` and/or structure the `Order` class to get this to work?